# Find the maximum volume of an open top prism with an isosceles base, if the surface area is constant and length is 1.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How can I find the maximum volume of the prism if its length is 1m and the surface area is a constant $S$?

Take the prism's isosceles base to have dimensions $a$ as the longest side, $b$ as the equal sides, and $\theta$ as the angle between $a$ and $b$.

By length, I mean the distance from end to end of the prism.

This prism has both bases closed and the side with area $a$ open, as it will be used to catch falling water. It will look similar to this, but triangular:

[image]

I have tried: 
$$V = \frac{1}{2} ab \sin \theta$$
$$S = ab \sin \theta +2b$$
$$S = 2V + 2b$$
$$V = \frac{S-2b}{2}$$

I have tried the same approach with a rectangle, and at this point I took the derivative to find the maximum volume. I do not understand how to do that here, since it seems the maximum volume is where $b = 0$, which doesn't make sense. If I have made a mistake, I can't find it.

Comment: What do you mean with length, is this the hight of the prism?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes, from one base to the other.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: For the prism we get

$$V=A\cdot 1m$$ with $A=\frac{1}{2}b^2\sin(\gamma)$
For the Surface we get

$Const=2bm^2+\frac{1}{2}b^2\sin(\gamma)$
where $b$ the two equal sidelength of the triangle, $a$ denotes the third side and $\gamma$ is the angle between the thwo sides $b$ ($m$ denotes the length in meter)

Comment: Sorry, I will clarify my post: the open face is the side of a, not one of the bases. This shape is to be used as a gutter, to catch dripping water from a roof.

Comment: Then the Surface is without $am^2$

Comment: Thank you, I have edited using your post, but still get the same result.